# Easy question on autoregressive LLM

Tags: nlp, transformer, language-model

For LLM decoder, how exactly is the K, Q, V for each decoding step?

Say my input prompt is "today is a" (good day).

At t= 0 (generation step 0):
K, Q, V are the projections of the sequence ("today is a")
Then say the next token generated is "good"

**At t= 1(generation step 1):
Which one is true:**

- K, Q, V are the projections of the sequence ("today is a good")

OR

- K, Q, are the projections of the sequence ("today is a") , V is the projection of sequence ("good")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At t=1: K, Q, V are the projections of the sequence "today is a good".

However, given that the computations of the first tokens were already done in the previous step, usually, there is some sort of caching mechanism to save their repeated computation in the following steps.

Comment: thanks for the comment, would you please explain (at a high level), how would the caching mechanism work?

Comment: Keeping in memory the tensors with the hidden states of all layers from the previous tokens and using them in the computation of the attention heads instead of computing them.